# erro ERR_HTTP2_INADEQUATE_TRANSPORT_SECURITY

Tags: visual-studio

the error happens on a windows 10 home (updated) with visual studio, the visual studio certificate is right (I think), not what it can be, if I put it in the project to run http1, it works, that and with any project.

I tried deleting the certificate and creating it again to no avail.